# Spring Integration JMS creating ActiveMQ queue instead of topic

Tags: java, spring-integration, activemq-classic, spring-jms, spring-messaging

I am trying to use an ActiveMQ broker to deliver a message to two consumers listening on an automatic topic, employing Spring Integration facilities.

Here are my configuration beans (in common between publishers and subscribers):

```
@Value("${spring.activemq.broker-url}")
String brokerUrl;

@Value("${spring.activemq.user}")
String userName;

@Value("${spring.activemq.password}")
String password;

@Bean
public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
    ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory();
    connectionFactory.setBrokerURL(brokerUrl);
    connectionFactory.setUserName(userName);
    connectionFactory.setPassword(password);
    return connectionFactory;
}

@Bean
public JmsListenerContainerFactory<?> jsaFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
        DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer) {
    DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
    factory.setPubSubDomain(true); //!!
    configurer.configure(factory, connectionFactory);
    return factory;
}

@Bean
public JmsTemplate jmsTemplate() {
    JmsTemplate template = new JmsTemplate();
    template.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
    template.setPubSubDomain(true); //!!
    return template;
}
```

Here are beans for consumers:

```
@Bean(name = "jmsInputChannel")
public MessageChannel jmsInputChannel() {
    return new PublishSubscribeChannel();
}

@Bean(name = "jmsInputFlow")
public IntegrationFlow buildReceiverFlow() {        
    return IntegrationFlows.from(Jms.messageDrivenChannelAdapter(connectionFactory()).destination("myTopic"))
            .channel("jmsInputChannel").get();
}

//Consumes the message.
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel="jmsInputChannel")
public void receive(String msg){
    System.out.println("Received Message: " + msg);
}
```

And these are the beans for the producer:

```
@Bean(name = "jmsOutputChannel")
public MessageChannel jmsOutputChannel() {
    return new PublishSubscribeChannel();
}

@Bean(name = "jmsOutputFlow")
public IntegrationFlow jmsOutputFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(jmsOutputChannel()).handle(Jms.outboundAdapter(connectionFactory())
            .destination("myTopic")
    ).get();
}



private static int counter = 1;

@Scheduled(initialDelay=5000, fixedDelay=2000)
public void send() {
     String s = "Message number " + counter;
     counter++;
     jmsOutputChannel().send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(s).build());
}
```

I am NOT using an embedded ActiveMQ broker. I am using one broker, one producer and two consumers each in their own (docker) container.

My problem is that, while I have invoked `setPubSubDomain(true)` on both the `JmsListenerContainerFactory` and the `JmsTemplate`, my "topics" behave as queues: one consumer prints all the even-numbered messages, while the other prints all the odd-numbered ones.

In fact, by accessing the ActiveMQ web interface, I see that my "topics" (i.e. under the /topics.jsp page) are named `ActiveMQ.Advisory.Consumer.Queue.myTopic` and `ActiveMQ.Advisory.Producer.Queue.myTopic`, and "myTopic" does appear in the queues page (i.e. /queues.jsp).

The nodes get started in the following order:

- AMQ broker
- Consumer 1
- Consumer 2
- Producer

The first "topic" that gets created is `ActiveMQ.Advisory.Consumer.Queue.myTopic`, while the producer one appears only after the producer has started, obviously.

I am not an expert on ActiveMQ, so maybe the fact of my producer/consumer "topics" being named ".Queue" is just misleading. However, I do get the semantics described in the [official ActiveMQ documentation](http://activemq.apache.org/how-does-a-queue-compare-to-a-topic.html) for queues, rather than topics.

I have also looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38643740/implementing-publish-subscribe-using-spring-integration-jms-in-activemq) already, however all of my employed channels are already of the PublishSubscribeChannel kind.

What I need to achieve is having all messages delivered to all of my (possibly > 2) consumers.

**UPDATE:** I forgot to mention, my `application.properties` file already does contain `spring.jms.pub-sub-domain=true`, along with other settings.

Also, the version of Spring Integration that I am using is 4.3.12.RELEASE.

The problem is, I still get a RR-load-balanced semantics rather than a publish-subscribe semantics.
As for what I can see in the [link](http://activemq.apache.org/advisory-message.html) provided by @Hassen Bennour, I would expect to get a `ActiveMQ.Advisory.Producer.Topic.myTopic` and a  `ActiveMQ.Advisory.Consumer.Topic.myTopic` row on the list of all topics. Somehow I think I am not using well the Spring Integration libraries, and thus I am setting up a Queue when I want to set up a Topic.

**UPDATE 2**: Sorry about the confusion. `jmsOutputChannel2` is in fact `jmsOutputChannel` here, I have edited the main part. I am using a secondary "topic" in my code as a check, something for the producer to send message to and receive replies itself. The "topic" name differs as well, so... it's on a separate flow entirely.

I did achieve a little progress by changing the receiver flows in this way:

```
@Bean(name = "jmsInputFlow")
public IntegrationFlow buildReceiverFlow() {        
    //return IntegrationFlows.from(Jms.messageDrivenChannelAdapter(connectionFactory()).destination("myTopic"))
            //.channel("jmsInputChannel").get();
return IntegrationFlows.from(Jms.publishSubscribeChannel(connectionFactory()).destination("myTopic")) //Jms.publishSubscribeChannel() rather than Jms.messageDrivenChannelAdapter()
            .channel("jmsInputChannel").get();
}
```

This produces an advisory topic of type `Consumer.Topic.myTopic` rather than `Consumer.Queue.myTopic` on the broker, AND indeed a topic named just `myTopic` (as I can see from the topics tab). However, once the producer starts, a `Producer.Queue` advisory topic gets created, and messages get sent there while not being delivered.

The choice of adapter in the input flow seems to determine what kind of advisory consumer topic gets created (Topic vs Queue when switching to `Jms.publishSubscribeChannel()` from `Jms.messageDrivenChannelAdapter()`). However, I haven't been able to find something akin for the output flow.

**UPDATE 3**: Problem solved, thanks to @Hassen Bennour. Recap:

I wired the `jmsTemplate()` in the producer's `Jms.outboundAdapter()`

```
@Bean(name = "jmsOutputFlow")
public IntegrationFlow jmsOutputFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(jmsOutputChannel()).handle(Jms.outboundAdapter(jsaTemplate())
            .destination("myTopic")
    ).get();
}
```

And a more complex configuration for the consumer `Jms.messageDrivenChannelAdapter()`:

```
@Bean(name = "jmsInputFlow")
public IntegrationFlow buildReceiverFlow() {        
    return IntegrationFlows.from(Jms.messageDrivenChannelAdapter(
        Jms.container(connectionFactory(),"myTopic")
        .pubSubDomain(true).get()) )
        .channel("jmsInputChannel").get();
}
```

Though **this** is probably the smoothest and most flexible method, having such a bean...

```
@Bean
public Topic topic() {
    return new ActiveMQTopic("myTopic");
}
```

to wire as a destination for the adapters, rather than just a String.

Thanks again.

Comment: jmsOutputChannel2().send() sends messages to jmsOutputChannel() ??

Comment: That "2" was a mistake to report here on my side. As it is, I am merely sending Strings directly on the message channel `jmsOutputChannel()` itself, which is linked to the `Jms.outboundAdapter()` via the IntegrationFlow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add spring.jms.pub-sub-domain=true to application.properties

or

```
@Bean
public JmsListenerContainerFactory<?> jsaFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
        DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer) {
    DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
    // the configurer will use PubSubDomain from application.properties if defined or false if not
    //so setting it on the factory level need to be set after this
    configurer.configure(factory, connectionFactory);
    factory.setPubSubDomain(true);
    return factory;
}
```

`ActiveMQ.Advisory.Consumer.Queue.myTopic` is an Advisory topic for a Queue named myTopic 
take a look here to read about Advisory
http://activemq.apache.org/advisory-message.html

**UPDATE :**

update your definitions like below

```
@Bean(name = "jmsOutputFlow")
public IntegrationFlow jmsOutputFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(jmsOutputChannel()).handle(Jms.outboundAdapter(jmsTemplate())
            .destination("myTopic")
    ).get();
}

@Bean(name = "jmsInputFlow")
public IntegrationFlow buildReceiverFlow() {        
    return IntegrationFlows.from(Jms.messageDrivenChannelAdapter(
            Jms.container(connectionFactory(),"myTopic")
            .pubSubDomain(true).get()) )
            .channel("jmsInputChannel").get();
}
```

**or define the Destination as a topic and replace destination("myTopic") by destination(topic())**

```
@Bean
public Topic topic() {
    return new ActiveMQTopic("myTopic");
}
```

Comment: The property was already set, I forgot to mention. I also tried moving the `factory.setPubSubDomain(true)` line after the call to the configurer. I am having **exactly** the same same behaviour.